# How do I make a stack view or container view wrap contents?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

As a beginner iOS developer transitioning from an Android code base, I am trying to find the equivalent in iOS for the following UI layout.

In Android, if you want a container that adjusts its height automatically based on its internal content, you would do something like the following:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

How can this be accomplished with autolayout through the storyboard? How can I set the width or height of a `StackView` or `ContainerView` to be `wrap_content`?

Comment: It depends on what the content is. Many components can size themselves based on their content and if you add constraints between components then autolayout can maintain spacing.

Comment: You need to provide more information. For example if you set a text field's number of lines to 0 then it will expand as required. A UIImageView can expand to hold the image if you constrain only its top/left or bottom/right. A button will never wrap onto more than one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish the same on ios by using UIStackView (Verticl/Horizontal) or UIScrollview

let me explain the whole process in scrollview

1- drag a scrollview to your view controller in storyboard file/Xib

2- give the storyboard leading , trailing , top , bottom constraints to the main view

3- drag a UIView (contentView) inside the scrollView and hook it's leading , trailing , top , bottom constraints to the scrollview

4- control-drag from the contentView to the mainView and select Equal-widths constraint

until this step you have a scrollview that is ready to be wrapped according to the inner size of it's components

5- drag a UILabel and hook it's leading , trailing , top , bottom constraints to the contentView

in runtime change the content of that label and the scrollview will wrap according to the label content